# Free jqGrid clearing local data

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I'm using [Oleg's Free jqGrid 4.15.2](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

I have following HTML test page

```
<input type="text" id="edtBarcode" class="barcode" placeholder="Scan Here" />
<table id="grid"></table>
```

And following Javascript code

```
$(function () {
    CreateGrid();
    $("#edtBarcode").keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            gridData.push({'barcode': '1234567'});

            alert(gridData.length);
            CreateGrid();
            $("#edtBarcode").focus();
            return false;
        }
    });
});

var gridData = [];

function CreateGrid() {
    alert('1: ' + gridData.length);
    $('#grid').GridUnload();
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: gridData,
        colNames: ['barcode'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'barcode', width: '150px'}],
        viewrecords: true
    })
    alert('2: ' + gridData.length);
}
```

This code adds a new row to gridData every time enter is pressed on text box (simplified for purpose of this test) which does the job.

**Problem**
Every time `$('#grid').GridUnload();` is called the data in gridData is deleted too.

**Question**

- Is there any alternative to `$('#grid').GridUnload();` which reloads the data?

Please note that In actual scenario, there are calculations and server calls before adding the data to grid. Also during this call, rows on `gridData` might get modified too (e.g. combine same barcode rows to one record with count incremented).

**Edit:**

Using `CreateGrid(gridData.slice());` instead is working but I just consider it as a workaround and hoping there is a better way instead of duplicating data in memory.

Comment: You can use clearGridData (in case of Guriddo jqGrid) of place of gridUnload. This function clears the data and index and then you simple can add the new data with serGridParam and reload the grid. Also addRowData will do the same job very easy

Comment: I'm not sure, what you need to implement. Do you use **the same** `colModel` in `CreateGrid` function? In the case, you don't need to call `GridUnload` which destroy all structures of jqGrid and reduce all to initial empty `<table>`. Instead of that you can just replace `data` and trigger `reloadGrid`. In simplified folm it looks like `var p = $('#grid').jqGrid("getGridParam"); p.data = newData; $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");`.

Comment: @Oleg,  I didn't know I could access all grid data this way, I couldn't figure out a way to just replace the data and that is why I destroyed the grid as suggested by another answer in SO a few years back. Please post your comment as answer in case someone else have the same question. Also Is there a way to know if grid already created on an element except checking content of container?

Comment: BTW, Thanks for new jqgrid wiki